# Multiple WebElements from a list of any size using for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, xpath

I am trying to grab specific web elements from a list using xpath that is not a fixed length.

The xpath I'm using is  `//*[@id="node-1"]/td[4]`  where the "node" can be from 1 to whatever in number.  Everything else in the xpath remains the same.

For example, the webelements I'm interested in might be found in the xpath's as:

```
//*[@id="node-1"]/td[4]
//*[@id="node-2"]/td[4]
//*[@id="node-3"]/td[4]
//*[@id="node-4"]/td[4]
```

but the list can have varying amounts of nodes.

I need to generate a for loop (in java) that grabs each webelement in the xpath starting at "node-1" to however many nodes there are and then puts those elements into a list for later use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> puts those elements into a list for later use

following is simple way to do it.. with list for later use -

```
List<WebElement> nodelist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'node-')]"));

for (int i = 0; i < nodelist.size(); i++) {
    WebElement node = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='node-" + Integer.toString(i) + "']"));
    // do your logic here
}
```

nodelist is list you will have for later use

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach.

```
int numberOfNodes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'node-')]")).size();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
        WebElement node = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='node-" + Integer.toString(i) + "']"));
        // do your logic here
}
```